# Exibição dos dados pessoais em uma tabela

Tags: php

Bom dia
Gostaria de saber como exibir só o meu nome que está no banco de dados ao invés de exibir tudo em uma tabela.

public function all(){

```
    $sql = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario");
    $sql->execute();
    $rows = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);

    if (!$rows) {
        $_SESSION['cor']='danger';
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<b>Nenhum usuário cadastrado</b>";
    }

    return $rows;
}
```

Não seu se uso o "WHERE id" ou se tem outra forma mais fácil.

Comment: Se usar "Where id" vai restringir somente o registro com o id informado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie uma outra função para pegar o usuário pelo ID.

```
public function by_id($id_user){
    $sql = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id = ".$id_user);
    $sql->execute();
    $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);

    if (!$row) {
        $_SESSION['cor']='danger';
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<b>Nenhum usuário cadastrado</b>";
    }

    return $row;
}
```